# Excel, Split name with more than one words of first name or last name or middle name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I separate the `last name` `middle initial` and `first name`

I have a name with two or more given name or last name or middle name for example

```
Mendoza, John Lloyd Dela Cruz
Torres, Michael Pineda
```

How can i split that if I have different count of words per column? and get only the first letter for `middle name`? Is this possible? If not can you suggest me a solution. I have many data

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With this description, no way, because you don´t know the number of word or length of any item.

Comment: This can be done using FIND() looking for spaces, then find() inside FIND() to locate the position of the second space etc first example =left(A1,find(",",A1,1)-1) will give the name before the comma... after that you can work with left() mid() right() find() and len()

Comment: how about I should just get the last word for middle initial?

Comment: Apply and try what I suggested... Have you even checked the help for each of the functions I suggested?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing out First and Last name from Excel field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853586/parsing-out-first-and-last-name-from-excel-field)

Comment: @SolarMike I already tried many of that sometimes its splitting also the first name and sometimes it doesn't have a value

Comment: As I said, look for the spaces... I have pointed tou towards functions with an example - I don’t have time to craft an answer now....

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean I tried I'm getting the last name right but when it comes to first name and middle name the others are working and the others is not

Comment: Anyway thank you. I will gonna try more.

Comment: Just tried text-to-columns, looks so much quicker and then you only need to select what you want , for the initial use left()...

Comment: The link that provided that say answered my question is wrong. That didn't fully answer my question just the part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is almost identical to this question:[extract names in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929340/extract-names-in-excel/57949352#57949352) except you only want to return the initial for the middle name.

As a result, my following answer is pretty much the same as the one I gave to the above question except adding a little twist of finding the initial for the middle name.

> **Note: Method 1 will work in the case that first name contains only one word; Method 2 will work only if both first name and last name is one word.**

[image: Solution]

> **Method 1** Using LEFT+RIGHT+MID+FIND functions

First Name: `=MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1)-FIND(",",A2)-2)`

Middle Name: `=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1)),1)`

Last Name: `=LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1)`

The logic to find **First Name** is to find the position of `,(space)` and the second `(space)` and return the characters in between. The logic for **Middle Name** is to find the second `(space)` and return whatever is on the right.

> **Method 2** Using FILTERXML+SUBSTITUTE functions

First Name: `=FILTERXML("<data><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7,",","")," ","</a><a>")&"</a></data>","/data/a[2]")`

Middle Name: `=LEFT(FILTERXML("<data><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7,",","")," ","</a><a>")&"</a></data>","/data/a[3]"),1)`

Last Name: `=FILTERXML("<data><a>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7,",","")," ","</a><a>")&"</a></data>","/data/a[1]")`

The logic is to use **SUBSTITUTE** to convert the full name into something like the following:

`<data><a>`Last Name`</a><a>`First Name`</a><a>`Middle Name`</a></data>`

Then use **FILTERXML** to return the desired name based on its order `1, 2 or 3` within the XML script.

For the logic behind this formula you may give a read to this article: [Extract Words with FILTERXML](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/).

Comment: Sadly the result on your picture is wrong. The middle initial of the first one should be `D` and the first name is `John Lloyd` I think its really impossible for now

Comment: @Jovs fair enough my solution will not work if the first name is more than one word and it is inconsistent across board.

Comment: Thank you for the effort anyway. Your answer will work if I have one word only per first name and middle name

Comment: @Jovs it will work if the first name is one word and the middle name starts in the third word regardless how many words are there in middle name :)

Comment: Oh yeah. Anyway thank you. I'll up vote this. It can certainly help.

Comment: For family names like Da Silva Dos Santos you can add hyphens manually Da-Silva-Dos-Santos... If 95% are automatic then correcting the few should not be much of a challenge...